# Excel VBA - Select first cell in filtered listobject data

Tags: excel, vba

I want my macro to select or goto the first row of filtered data in a `listobject`. I am trying this code but I get an error.

```
activesheet.AutoFilter.Range.offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 2).select
```

I would like to do this because if the user filters the data, whilst he has scrolled mid-way through the sheet, then he might not see all of the filtered data because of the freezed panes.

Comment: What is the error? Post the relevant part of the code that leads to this line, too.

Comment: this line errors out when dealing with a listobject

Comment: I was after the exact error message, but never mind ....

Answer (score 0):

ok I figured this out:

```
Application.Goto lo_f.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1), True
```

Need to use `Goto` in order to bring the screen to the filtered cell.